# Cant add AdMob on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

Im just tryng to put admob (4.3.1) on a android app (3.3, api 10) on eclipse (Version: 3.7.2)

following the [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals), at the start i have a error on
    `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

and then in Adding a com.google.ads.adview... I just didint know what to do, I tried 2 or 3 times, but it's not clear to me if I have to delete the `Import` from my project and put that or put below or above. I downloaded the sample but I seem to have errors in the activity.

So I just tried to [create a banner XML](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml) and with no problems. I saved as a .apk, put on my phone (the device what I gave the device ID for test) and it just won't open, it forces close every time I try. I have almost 10 free apps on the market just waiting for ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that api 10 is version `2.3.3`, not `3.3`.  The `screenSize` and `smallestScreenSize` configChanges required by AdMob were not introduced into the Android framework until Android 3.2 (api 13).  So if your project.properties has something lower than `android-13`, your app simply won't compile.

As for adding the AdView, I'm not sure I understand your problem.  The example code is open-sourced [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/examples/Fundamentals/src/com/google/example/ads/fundamentals/BannerSample.java?repo=examples-android).  Perhaps you could point to the line that is giving you issues.

Comment: so there's no way to put admob on anything lower than honeycomb?

Comment: So your target in project.properties has to be 13 or higher.  This only means your app compiles against 3.2.  You can run on devices down to 1.5 by specifying `<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="3"/>` in your manifest.